# How do i activate a Feature when a subsite is created

Tags: feature

I have a web template that users can create sub sites from.  I want to activate a feature when the subsite is created e.g. create list, columns etc for that sub site only.

How would i approach doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you can use [Feature stapling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861862%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Also see [What is “feature stapling”?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/33988/627).

Comment: thanks for the reply. is FeatureStapling the best way to do this? are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when you want a **FEATURE activated for any web created in the farm** using a specific web template, you use FEATURE STAPLING.

But, if you want a **FEATURE activated for any web created in a particular Site Collection only**, you should use WEB PROVISIONED event. For more information on, WebProvisioned event, check here: http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/webprovisioned-event-receiver-practical.html