# Apply look and feel to mysite automatically

Tags: 2013, my-site, theme

I would like to know how to apply a look and feel to all My Sites automatically including the Apps area of a mysite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to build a [*Feature Stapling*](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33985/what-is-feature-stapling) which sets the styling for My Sites. I'd recommend using [this tutorial](http://sharepointologic.blogspot.fi/2013/04/branding-sharepoint-2013-my-sites-with.html) to achieve the results you've required.

Feature Stapling is quite widely used, thus you'll have a great chance to find already available solutions to match your requirements.

Comment: Hi i have looked for a sample vs2012/2013 solution to no avail could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The above mentioned tutorial is for VS2012/SP2013 and works well. Another very similar tutorial is for example this one: http://frederik.se/how-to-brand-sharepoint-2013-team-sites-using-feature-stapling-in-vs/. Just don't mind the little word mistakes on the guide.. But what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Hi moe thanks for the info, i was looking for a sample solution i could edit for a quick win :-)

Comment: Well in that case both of these URLs are the solution for you. They require close to nothing to be edited, but still give you the solution from start to the end.

Comment: Ok next quedtion, how the F do i mark your reply as the answer i only see ann 'add answer' button.

Comment: Maybe this helps you even a little :) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers