# Deploy solution across all the site collection in a web app

Tags: solution-deployment, feature-scope

I have an environment in which we have 1000's of site collection. We also create new site collection.

I want to deploy an event receiver which is available across all the site collections i.e web apllication.

I created a new solution and added event receiver to it. I deployed it at the root site collection with scope set as `Site`. The solution is only available in that particular site collection. I am not allowed to set the scope to `WebApplication` as i get the error message as :

> The Project Item "SetAlstomMP" cannot be deployed through a Feature
>   with WebApplication scope.    c:\users\133386\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TeamSite-SubSites\TeamSite-SubSites\Features\Feature1\Feature1.feature  TeamSite-SubSites

My basic requirement is that i want each of the subsite created in a site collection to inherit Master Page from the parent site. For which i was planning to write an event receiver.

Also, when new site collection is created i want the solution to be auto activated. Is this possible?

Can anyone please suggest if this is a correct approach? and how do i go ahead with the deployment?

Answer (score 1):

The *Site* scoped feature will be available for all site collections in the web application. If you want your feature to appear in all sub sites under site collection, then you should change the *Scope* to *Web*.

If you want your master page to be automatically set in the sub sites under a root site collection you can use `SPWebEventReceiver.WebProvisioned` event.

> Synchronous After event that fires after a subsite is fully
>   provisioned and the provisioning process has stopped, but does not
>   fire when the root web site of a new site collection is created.

In order to activate the feature automatically on new site collection creation, you can add the *Site* scoped feature in `SiteFeatures` collection of site definition file named ONET.xml file, if you have custom site difintion. However, in case of OOB site definition, you can use [feature stapling](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33985/what-is-feature-stapling)

Comment: I am working on `WebProvisioned`, but as you mentioned a Site scoped feature will be available for all site collections, but that is exactly what is not happening. I have deployed the solution at the root site e.g `http://server02:2000/` and the solution is available in Site Collection feature but if i naviagete to `http://server02:2000/sites/a` then the feature is not available.

Comment: @Ishan, ar you sure you are checking the feature at right location. It shoud be in Site Settings -> Site Collection administration -> Site Collection features

Comment: Yes absolutely.. I checked in Site Collection feature and even manage site features (just incase).. i didn't find the feature..

Comment: i have deployed using VS, providing the URL as `http://server02:2000/`